# How to only show your device name in IOS Swift? Bluetooth (BLE)

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I am trying to only show my device name with scanning. I need it to show the device (name-numbers) at the end depending on how many devices is turn on. Right now it shows all devices within the range and I just want it to show my device name-numbers and nothing else. Can someone help me figure this out please?

Here is some code:

Here is the first class I have for scanning.

```
 /*function that gets called if we get a peripheral found notification*/
@objc func peripheralFound(notification: NSNotification){
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return bluetoothConnection.peripherals.count
}

/*setting up a table cell which will display the name of the peripheral*/
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // return a cell with the peripheral name as text in the label
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
    let label = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel

    label.text = bluetoothConnection.peripherals[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].peripheral.name
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    return cell
}


/*if we select a given peripheral stop scanning for new ones. set selectedPeripheral to what we selected.  try to connect to selected peripheral*/

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    // the user has selected a peripheral, so stop scanning and proceed to the next view
    bluetoothConnection.manager.stopScan()
    selectedPeripheral = bluetoothConnection.peripherals[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].peripheral
    bluetoothConnection.manager.connect(selectedPeripheral!, options: nil)
    connectionTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(checkIfConnectSuccessful), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```

Here is what I do for a different class.

```
//initialize core bluetooth
init(delegate: BluetoothClassDelegate){
    super.init()
    //change later
    self.delegate = delegate
    manager = CBCentralManager(delegate:self, queue: nil)
}

/// Start scanning for peripherals
func startScan() {
    guard manager.state == .poweredOn else { return }

    // start scanning for peripherals with correct service UUID
    manager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: false])
}

/* Called when BLE turns on or off*/
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    if central.state == .poweredOn {
        central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
    }
    else{
        print("Bluetooth not available")
    }
}

/* Called any time a peripheral is discovered
 discovered a peripheral with the defined uuid so add it to the list of peripherals available, reorganize by RSSI, dont allow for duplicates*/

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    // check whether it is a duplicate
    for exisiting in peripherals {
        if exisiting.peripheral.identifier == peripheral.identifier { return }
    }
    if peripheral.name == nil {return}
    // add to the array, next sort & reload
    let theRSSI = RSSI.floatValue
    peripherals.append((peripheral: peripheral, RSSI: theRSSI))
    peripherals.sort { $0.RSSI < $1.RSSI }
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .foundPeripheral, object: nil)

}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    peripheral.delegate = self
    peripheral.discoverServices([myisscServiceUUID])
}

/* Called any time a service has been discovered for a given peripheral
 we have discovered a peripheral with a matching service uuid*/

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
    for service in peripheral.services! {
        if service.uuid == myisscServiceUUID {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics([myisscTxUUID, myisscRxUUID], for: service )
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried many things but it still shows me all the devices within the bluetooth range. Is there something I can do so it just shows me a unique name. REMINDER that I also need to show all the devices with the same device name but just different numbers at the end. If someone could help that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do. Do you want to limit discovery to a certain type of device?  If so you need to scan for a specific service that that device class is advertising rather than `nil`

Comment: Yes I am trying to limit discovery to a certain type of device name. How would you scan for a specific service?

Comment: You need to know the UUID of that service and specify it in `scanForPeripherals` instead of `nil`  You could also check the discovered device name and only add it to the array if it starts with your desired name string

Comment: I have tried changing it to this and it would not..    /// Start scanning for peripherals
    func startScan() {
        guard manager.state == .poweredOn else { return }
        
        // start scanning for peripherals with correct service UUID
        manager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [myisscServiceUUID], options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: false])
    }

Comment: and also this..                                                          
 /* Called when BLE turns on or off*/
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [myisscServiceUUID], options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: false]
            )
        }
        else{
            print("Bluetooth not available")
        }
    }

Comment: Is `myisscServiceUUID` being advertised by your peripheral?  Is the value assigned to that variable correct?

Comment: Yes, this is what I have. var myisscServiceUUID     = CBUUID(string: "49535343-FE7D-4AE5-8FA9-9FAFD205E455")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190055/discussion-between-paulw11-and-azerswag).